# Отправка данных через xhr.send(finalFiles); и их обработка в php

Tags: javascript, php

Есть форма. Большая часть данных с нее собирается и обрабатывается в PHP, кроме одного инпута

```html
<div id="drop-zone">
  <p>Перетащите файлы сюда...</p>
  <div id="clickHere">или нажмите здесь..
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="files" multiple />
  </div>
  <div id='filename'></div>
</div>
```

собираю все это в массив (если нужно - могу показать код), массив отправляю таким образом:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://zayavlenie.com.ua/mail-dev.php', true);
// The rest of the code will go here...
// Set up a handler for when the request finishes.
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // File(s) uploaded.
    uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Отправка';
  } else {
    alert('An error occurred!');
  }
};
console.log(formData);
console.log(finalFiles);
xhr.send(finalFiles);
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  // обработать ошибку
  alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
} else {
  alert(xhr.responseText); // responseText -- текст ответа.
}
}
```

На стороне сервера пытаюсь прослушать вообще все что приходит таким образом:

```
<?
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$post = $_POST;
var_dump($post);
echo('<hr>');
$req = $_REQUEST;
var_dump($req);
echo('<hr>');
```

На выходе получаю данные с фомры которые обрабатываются php скриптом, но не значение поля `input type="file"`
Массив $_FILES возвращает следующее

```
array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } } string(0) "" 
Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/zayavlenie/zayavlenie.com.ua/mail-dev.php on line 227

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/zayavlenie/zayavlenie.com.ua/mail-dev.php on line 228

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/zayavlenie/zayavlenie.com.ua/mail-dev.php on line 229
```

Как правильно отправлять данные при помощи xhr.send()

Comment: вопрос должен быть один

Comment: @Ипатьев У меня вопрос один: Как правильно формировать и отправлять данные через xhr.send() и обрабатывать в php функцией mail()?

Comment: "у меня вопрос один: вопрос номер 1 и вопрос номер 2" :)))

Comment: @Ипатьев )) Ладно, ответьте мне пожалуйста на первый вопрос, как это правильно делать?

Comment: я думаю, правильно будет этого не делать

Comment: @Ипатьев всмысле?

Answer (score 0):

1. Со стороны **клиента**, файлы должны отправляться через объект `FormData`, это значит что файлы нужно преобразовать, например, вот так:

   ```
   var inputElem = document.getElementById('files');  
   var files = inputElem.files;  
   var data = new FormData();  
   Array.from(files).forEach(file => data.append(file.name, file));
   ```

> Проверка наличия элементов в FormData осуществляется методом `has`
>   (`data.has(NAME)`), а получение `get` (`data.get(NAME)`).

1.2 Отправка данных осуществляется через `Content-Type : multipart/form-data` (по умолчанию).

```
var async = true;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', URL_NAME, async);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); //этот header добавляется по умолчанию
xhr.send(files);
```

---

Пример.

```js
var URL_NAME = 'http://zayavlenie.com.ua/mail-dev.php';
var async = true;

var inputElem = document.getElementById('files');
var ip1 = document.getElementById('ip1');
var ip2 = document.getElementById('ip2');

var data = new FormData();

function collectFiles() {
   var files = inputElem.files;  
   Array.from(files).forEach(file => data.append(file.name, file));
}

function collectInputs() {
   data.append('ip1', ip1.value);
   data.append('ip2', ip2.value);
}

function send() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', URL_NAME, async);
  xhr.send(data);
}


function submit() {
   collectFiles();
   collectInputs();
   send();
}
```

```html
<div class="another-inputs">
  <input id="ip1" type="text"/>
  <input id="ip2" type="text"/>
</div>

<div id="drop-zone">
  <p>Перетащите файлы сюда...</p>
  <div id="clickHere">или нажмите здесь..
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="files" multiple />
  </div>
  <div id='filename'></div>
  
  <button onClick="submit()">SEND</button>
</div>
```

2. На **сервере** информацию о файле можно просмотреть в глобальном массиве $_FILES.
   C механизмом загрузки файлов методом POST можно ознакомиться [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php). По сути все сводится к получению названия файла ([basename](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php)), и его перемещению в существующею директорию ([move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php))

В Вашем случае файл mail-dev.php будет приблизительно такой.

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';

foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename(value['name']);
    move_uploaded_file(value['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    //... + обработка ошибок
}
```

---

Итак, что бы отправить файл нужно:
- собрать файлы из формы/инпута;
- преобразовать собранные файлы в объект FormData;
- отправить аякс multipart/form-data;
- на сервере (mail-dev.php) обработать файлы.

Comment: Здесь не учтен самый главный вопрос автора: он отправляет файлы отдельно от всей формы, а ждет их в том же самом обработчике.

Comment: @Ипатьев так он, как я понял аяксом шлет, собрав их в кучу

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick У меня в форме несколько инпутов. Они принимаются в php через $_POST с ними всё ок. Проблемы только с input type="file". Если можно переписать обработчик так чтобы в аяксе собрать инпуты со всей формы и в php отправить уже то что пойдет в mail() - вообще шикарно. Но я так понял, это невозможно.

Comment: @Антон возможно, почему нет? Отредактировал пример. Посмотрите его внимательнее. Добавил рандомных инпутов. Они тоже добавляются в объект FormData.

Comment: @Антон функция `collectFiles`  добавляет файлы, функция `collectInputs` добавляет информацию по другим инпутам. Все это добавляется в результирующий объекта data (ифо по инпутам + файлы). И эта data отправляется на сервер

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick премного благодарен. Буду сейчас разбираться, если что - обращусь).

Comment: @Антон да кстати, тут не нужен заголовок xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); выже передаете не только файлы